# Odd Python Errors

Tags: python, function

I am making a python script that suggests new music to you, but for some reason i am getting a lot of errors. Script is not finished, but here it is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("This is to help you find new bands!")
pop = 0
def indie():
    global indie
    global classic_rock
    global metal
    global pop
    indie = 0
    classic_rock = 0
    metal = 0
    pop = 0
    indie += 3
    classic_rock -= 1
    metal -= 1.5
    pop -= 3
def notindie():
    global indie
    indie += 1
def classicrock():
    global classic_rock
    classic_rock += 2
def notclassicrock():
    global classic_rock
    classic_rock -= 1
def popp():
    global pop
    global indie
    pop += 3
    indie -= 3
def notpop():
    global pop
    global metal
    pop -= 1
    metal += 1
def notmetal():
    global metal
    global pop
    metal -= 3
    pop += 1
def metal():
    global metal
    global pop
    global indie
    global classicrock
    classicrock += 1
    metal += 3
    indie -= 1
    pop -= 4
que = input("Do you consider yourself to be a hipster? (Yes/No) ")
if que == 'yes':
    indie()
if que == 'no':
    notindie()
que2 = input("Do you like the Rolling Stones? (Yes/No) ")
if que2 == 'yes':
    classicrock()
if que2 == 'no':
    notclassicrock()
que3 = input("Do you like Britney Spears? (Yes/No) ")
if que3 == 'yes':
    popp()
if que3 == 'no':
    notpop()
que4 = input("Do you like Metallica? (Yes/No) ")
if que4 == 'no':
    notmetal()
if que4 == 'yes':
    metal()
```

if i enter yes for do you like metallica, i get the error

```
File "tastepy.py", line 69, in <module>
    metal()
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

if i enter in no for the hipster question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tastepy.py", line 54, in <module>
    notindie()
  File "tastepy.py", line 19, in notindie
    indie += 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'function' and 'int'
```

I get these although there is no float anything in metal()
anybody know what is going on?

Comment: I recommend you read up about [dicts](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and [lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).  Your implementation is about as graceful as a turtle in a tutu.

Comment: whaddaya mean, implementation...

Comment: I mean that you're using 70 lines of code to write something that shouldn't take more than 20. You're not taking advantage of the structure of the python language. I would recommend examining other people's code, and reading the python language tutorials at [python.org](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the same names for your functions as your variables, and they are clobbering each other.  Try using different names, e.g. for functions `likes_metal()` and for the variable `metal_score`.

Also you should declare and initialize your globals at the global level, not within the `indie` function.

Comment: what do you mean at the global level, outside the function you mean?

Comment: It's also not recommended that you use globals in the first place. It's better to pass values in the function parameters.

Comment: @JOEEEE yes, just like you currently have `pop = 0` in the 2nd line.  As @Joel said, globals are not great form, but you're already using them (or trying to), so this is how you do it properly.

Comment: but how would i do it with the variables in the function parameters?

Answer (score 1):

you are using the same names for your functions and your global variables. consequently when you run any function you delete all the functions and replace them with ints or floats